# How to use dynamic function name in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to optimize the following program by using `for` loops

```
t = 0:0.1:100;   
conc = rand(size(t));

syms x

equ_1(x) = 10*x.^2+1;
equ_2(x) = 5*x.^3+10*x.^2;
equ_3(x) = 5*x.^3+10*x.^2;

y_1 = equ_1(conc);
y_2 = equ_2(conc);
y_3 = equ_3(conc);

p_1 = polyfit(t,y_1,1);
p_2 = polyfit(t,y_2,1);
p_3 = polyfit(t,y_3,1);

yfit_1 = p_1(1)*conc+p_1(2);
yfit_2 = p_2(1)*conc+p_2(2);
yfit_3 = p_2(1)*conc+p_2(2);

rms_er_1 = double(sqrt((sum((yfit_1-y_1).^2)./length(yfit_1))));
rms_er_2 = double(sqrt((sum((yfit_2-y_2).^2)./length(yfit_2))));
rms_er_3 = double(sqrt((sum((yfit_3-y_3).^2)./length(yfit_3))));


rms = [rms_er_1 rms_er_2 rms_er_3]
```

In this program. I have many equations and I can write them manually like `equ_1(x),equ_1(x),equ_1(x)` etc. After writing equations, will it be possible to write remaining programs by using for loops?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can pack your functions in a cell array and give your values as parameters while looping over this cell array

```
t = (0:0.1:100)';   
conc = rand(size(t));

% Packing your function handles in a cell array ( I do not have the 
% symbolic math toolbox, so I used function handles here. In your case you
% have to pack your equations equ_n(x) in between the curly brackets{} )
allfuns = {@(x) 10*x.^2+1, ...
    @(x) 5*x.^3+10*x.^2, ...
    @(x) 5*x.^3+10*x.^2};

% Allocate memory
y = zeros(length(t), length(allfuns));
p = zeros(2,length(allfuns));
yfit = zeros(length(t), length(allfuns));
rms = zeros(1, length(allfuns));

% Loop over all functions the cell, applying your functional chain
for i=1:length(allfuns)
    y(:,i) = allfuns{i}(t);
    p(:,i) = polyfit(t,y(:,i),1);
    yfit(:,i) = p(1,i)*conc+p(2,i);
    rms(:,i) = double(sqrt((sum((yfit(:,i)-y(:,i)).^2)./ ...
        length(yfit(:,i)))));
end
```

This leads to

```
>> rms

rms =

   1.0e+06 *

    0.0578    2.6999    2.6999
```

You can expand that to an arbitrary number of equations in `allfuns`.

Btw: You are fitting 1st order polynomials with `polyfit` to values calculated with 2nd and 3rd order functions. This leads of course to rough fits with high `rms`. I do not know how your complete problem looks like, but you could define an array `poly_orders` containing the polynomial order of each function in `allfuns`. If you give those values as parameter to the `polyfit` function in the loop, your fits will work way better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your solution save a lot of my time

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cellfun`

Here is an example.

Define in a .m

```
function y = your_complex_operation(f,x, t)
y_1 = f(x);
p_1 = polyfit(t,y_1,1);
yfit_1 = p_1(1)*x+p_1(2);
y = double(sqrt((sum((yfit_1-y_1).^2)./length(yfit_1))));
end
```

Then use `cellfunc`

```
funs{1}=@(x) 10*x.^2+1;
funs{2}=@(x) 5*x.^3+10*x.^2;
funs{3}=@(x) 5*x.^3+10*x.^2;
%as many as you need

t = 0:0.1:100;
conc = rand(size(t));

funs_res = cellfun(@(c) your_complex_operation(c,conc,t),funs);
```